# safari won't play a gif converted to mp4 or m4v

Tags: html, video, safari

I converted a gif composed of three images to mp4 and also to m4v (for Safari) to play in the html5 video player, however, Safari won't play either the `.mp4` nor the `.m4v` with the following

```
<video preload="yes" controls="true" >
<source src="./menu.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="./menu.m4v" type="video/m4v" />
</video>
```

However, if I use a proper video (i.e. not a converted gif) Safari (9.2) will play it using the above syntax, so I know the html5 video player is working in my browser, just not my converted gif.
Question, for a gif that's converted to a "movie of still" photos, do I have to set a different type i.e. `type="gif/m4v"` or is there another setting I have to activate?

I used ffmpeg to convert the gif to an mp4 but don't recall the exact command that I ran to do it.

Update
According to [this](https://techcrunch.com/2014/06/19/gasp-twitter-gifs-arent-actually-gifs/) TechCrunch article, Twitter uses mp4s instead of gifs so I'm assuming it should work on all browsers.

the mp4 file can be viewed here

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mvkzo8xe7is4rle/menu.mp4?dl=0

Comment: How did you convert the gifs to mp4/m4v? maybe the converter is problematic?

Comment: Does it work in other browsers?

Comment: @faintsignal it works in chrome (the only other one I tried)

Comment: @Dekel I don't remember, I did it a few days ago and have looked at several different instructions to do it.  Maybe I'll try a few and experiment. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Link to one of these gifs? Or else check with a tool like `MediaInfo` (download) that your mp4 has h.264 codec made with baseline profile.

Comment: I won't be able to post the gif/mp4 until tomorrow

Comment: here's a link to the mp4 https://www.dropbox.com/s/mvkzo8xe7is4rle/menu.mp4?dl=0

Comment: @VC.One that tool you suggested isn't available to me

Comment: Try this version in your Safari : [**MP4 video link**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kb6dbs42615lu3w/menu_v2.mp4?dl=0). Let me know how it goes...

Comment: @VC.One that's perfect. Thank you very much. Can you please explain how you did it in an answer, if possible please also reference why it doesn't need to be `.m4v` file to play in Safari (which I had read elsewhere it needs to be, or maybe that's just for iPad/iPhone).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the video encoding, specifically the H.264 Profile setting, used with video codec.

Your current video is encoded as : `High 4:4:4 Predictive @ Level 2.2` which seems unusual for a browser video (and possibly won't decode on some mobile devices).

**Solution :**

In your encoder, choose an H.264 Profile of either `Baseline` or `Main`.

This [**working video**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kb6dbs42615lu3w/menu_v2.mp4?dl=0) uses `Main @ L3.1`

Using [**FFmpeg**](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) you can produce a new video under `Main` profile (which is suitable for your dimensions *width 480 X height 640*).

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v main -level:v 3.1 -an output.mp4
```

**Useful Notes :**

- You can [**check here**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html) some Apple recommended profiles (see **Point.11**). It is expected the video is using `4:2:0` sampling, not the problematic `4:4:4` in the not-working video.
- [**Wowza.com explains**](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-find-apple-ios-device-supported-profile-and-level-information) Profiles and Levels for mobile devices.
- A `Baseline` Profile would guarantee playback on even older devices (eg: iPhone 3 or older).

Comment: You sir, are a legend. I had already tried all html attributes like `autoplay playsinline` etc. None of them worked. The video played perfectly on SOME iPads but not on others. Even stranger: Of four videos of the same codec, three would play on the same iPad but the fourth did not. Converting the video with the command you posted solved the problem in the end. Thank you so much, I would have never figured this out by myself.